# SSL Auth to proxy using Certificate on Client-side

Tags: webserver, certificate-authority, openssl, http-proxy, ldap

The question may need to be reworded.

The server-side is set up with Squid3 acting as an Authenticating proxy by way of LDAP. I did this for testing purposes to make sure everything was working.

I would like to have the client-side authenticate using something like a certificate or the like so that the need to physically put in cred isn't needed.

Is this a possibility? This is my first real jump into this sort of thing, so by all means ask for more clarification and I will do my best to be more specific (if possible, haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if it is possible to negate the need for "login" authentication by using certificate based authentication?

If so, then yes you certainly can provided that your users don't have roles which determine their access levels to the service (authorisation). Furthermore, you could also achieve mutual authentication so that both the server and client identify themselves as authentic (prevent man-in-the-middle attacks). I recommend that you research SSL and see what it can do for you!

I hope this is useful to you :)